# Error using method saveAll(list) of ElasticsearchRepository and RestHighLevelClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I used org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch version 6.8 and for connectivity I used TransportClient. I then decided to upgrade to version 7.6 and since TransportClient is Deprecated, I had to use the connection to elastic via the RestHighLevelClient. I'm using a repository to work with an elastic data in springframework. But now I don't have elastic data storage through a repository working. My repository is inherited from the ElasticsearchRepository interface. I use the standard saveAll method.

I have a list of MyPostgresModel and I need to save that into Elastic. I want to do quickly that's why I use @Transactional and use saveAll method with Iterable. MyPostgresModel has toDocument method to return MyElasticModel object.

This is works: `myElasticRepository.save(users.get(0).toDocument());`
And this isn't works: `myElasticRepository.saveAll(() -> users.stream().map(MyPostgresModel::toDocument).iterator());`

I have no idea. Why not? That also returns *"type is missing;7930: type is missing;7931:.."* error. And the debuger tells me that elastic responses "400 Bad Request" status - data validation is not going.

Before I used the TransportClient everything was OK and after all TransportClient and RestHighLevelClient use a common ElasticsearchOperations interface...

I use the following config class for connection:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.project.elastic.repository")
public class ElasticConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.elastic.url}")
    private String url;

    @Override
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        return RestClients.create(ClientConfiguration.create(url)).rest();
    }
}
```

Here is the example of my elastic model:

```
@Data
@Document(indexName = "user", type = "_doc", createIndex = false)
public class ElasticUser {

    @Id
    private final String id;
    private final String address;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final List<String> phones;
    private final String gender;

    public ElasticUser(
            @NonNull String id,
            @NonNull String address,
            @NonNull String firstName,
            @NonNull String lastName,
            @NonNull List<String> phones,
            @Nullable String gender
    ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.address = address;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phones = phones;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

Service method:

```
    @Transactional
    public void saveUsers(@NonNull List<PostgresUser> users) {
//        myElasticRepository.save(users.get(0).toDocument());
        myElasticRepository.saveAll(() -> users.stream().map(PostgresUser::toDocument).iterator());
    }
```

Comment: I mean, that doesn't allow the list. And for every item on the list, it gives out its 'missing'.

Comment: Can you also upload this code to github, where we can clone and try it, I would require `pom` or `Gradle` as well.

Comment: it is difficult to deploy. I could make you a prototype but it will take time. Perhaps you could tell me which way to dig? I'm looking in the direction of the entityMapper in elasticsearch config now.

Comment: I've rest-client setup with me but not with spring boot and data, so I am not sure here issue is with spring or rest-client and at this stage its difficult to tell it, without reproducing it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with elasticsearch version. I used client with 7.6.2 and my elastic was 6.8.6.